# Why do I get NameError: uninitialized constant simply making a rake db:create on a new machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app on my virtual machine. environment is development and I work on it regularly. I pulled the code from the repo on a new nserver, and always with `RAILS_ENV` setted to `development` I called as first command `rake db:migrate` and I get that one of my class is NameError: uninitialized constant.

How is this possible if my code and environment are the same? Autoload on my virtual machine is configured in the right way if it works.

```
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '**', '**', '*')]
```

And the class that cannot be found is in `app/api/nameofclass/anothername/api.rb`.

Comment: How did you write the class definition in the file `app/api/nameofclass/anothername/api.rb`?

Comment: the precise path is : app/api/domains/DKIM/api.rb and the name is Domains::DKIM::Api

Comment: simply using your line instead of mine and running rake db:create is gives me TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
/var/www/qbpanel/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'. And using `+=` does not rewrite it.. but it concatenates the arrays....

Comment: Anyway, simply removing the "unnecessary" "**" as @mudasobwa said does not solve the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DKIM` as a name will be problematic since the autoloader maps that to `d_k_i_m/` in the path. Whenever possible avoid creating directories or files with capital letters in them, it causes chaos on case sensitive filesystems.

`app/api/domains/dkim/api.rb` should contain `Domains::Dkim::Api`.

If you want to use some non-standard naming system you'll have to force load your stuff manually, the auto-loader won't do it for you.

The auto-load directive should probably be:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'api')
```

You don't want to be including every single file in your autoload path.

Comment: It seems to work with a first try, will do more trials tomorrow and eventually mark your answer! thanks. One question, why the same code on my virtual machine work? and where did you find the way rails interpret "DKIM" as "d_k_i_m_", I searched everywhere

Comment: It might be interpreted as `dkim` as well, lower-case. `XyAb` is converted to `xy_ab` via the `underscore` function. A path like `DKIM` on a case-sensitive system won't work in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of your both lines:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W|lib app/api/**|
```